# limits of sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I can't find any faults with the logic, but still I am not a 100% sure. Is the following correct:

Let $a_n$ and $b_l$ be two sequences such that, $\exists \; L(n)\; \forall\; n$ for which $a_n  \leq b_l, \;\; \forall\; l\geq L(n)$. Thus, we have,
\begin{align}
    a_n \leq \lim_{l\rightarrow \infty} b_l \;\;\forall n \\
    \implies  \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_n \leq \lim_{l\rightarrow \infty} b_l
\end{align}

Comment: If the limits exist, then this is correct.

Comment: No. Counterexample: Let $a_n=1$ for all $n$ and $b_1=10$, $b_n=0$ for n>1

Comment: @Amr Maybe I'm reading the question wrong, but it seems the given condition is that for every $n$ we have $a_n\le b_l$ for all sufficiently large $l$.

Comment: Your order of quantors according to natural language instead of logical structure is somewhat confusing/misleading. What you mean is $\forall n\exists L\forall l\ge L\colon a_n\le b_l$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen. Yes. that's what I mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(a_n),(b_n):\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{R}$ so that $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$ 
$$\exists L_n\in \mathbb{R}\text{ so that }\forall l\in \mathbb{N}\ l\ge L_n\implies  a_n\le b_l$$
Then for fixed $n\in \mathbb{N}$ $\exists L_n\in \mathbb{R}$ so that 
$$\forall l\in \mathbb{N}\ l\ge L_n\implies  a_n\le b_l$$
If $(b_m)$ converges to $b\in \mathbb{R}$ then indeed
$$a_n\le b$$
As this holds $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}$, if $(a_m)$ converges to $a\in \mathbb{R}$ then
$$a\le b$$

The convergence of the two sequences is required for all this to hold

As a counterexample consider $a_n=(-1)^n$ and $b_n=(-1)^n+2013$ and $b'_n=\frac 1n+2013$